# Full screen width while maintaining document flow

Tags: html, css

I'm working within a site template that has `max-width: 960px` and I can't change this. But I've got a content page that needs to use the full screen. So something like this:

```html
<div class="site-template">  <--- same for all pages on the site
 <div class="my-content">    <--- my page
   ....
 </div>
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

I want `my-content` to take up the full screen width, but I can't see how.

`width:100%` would be 100% of the container, so only 960px.

`width: 100vw` has the right width, but the left edge still starts at the left of the template, not the viewport.

`position:absolute` would let me take up the whole width, but it's then out of the document flow, and so the footer is moved up underneath the content, when I want it to flow after my content.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please post more HTML and your CSS - your minimal code is a little too minimal :)

Comment: Can you just add CSS for this page to take max-width: 100% instead of max-width: 960px?

Comment: What about use `position:absolute` for `class="my-content"` and `position:relative` for `class="site-template"`. however we need more practic code from you.

Comment: @Keith: no, because that would mess up stuff in the header and footer that interacts with a massive amount of styling beyond my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.my-content {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc((960px - 100vw) / 2);
}

/* or for older browsers: */

.my-content {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
  
/* or for ancient as hell browsers: */

.my-content {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: -50vw;
}
```

Comment: Genius, works perfectly. Thanks!